# Run code on a Spring MVC app deployment

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection

I need to run some code when my application is deployed into a web container — and that class needs to be injectible by the Spring container.

I tried implementing `ServletContextListener` and registering the class as a listener, but injection wouldn't work.

What's the idiomatic way of doing this?

Comment: Listen for the context initialized event?

Answer (score 0):

To make your class injectible by Spring container, you can extend [SpringBeanAutowiringSupport](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/support/SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.html).